# SQL Query to select post title & post ID from a particular category

Tags: wpdb, sql

I am looking for SQL query to select post title & post ID from a particular category. I looked at wordpress table structure but it is really confusing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post' ,'posts_per_page' => 10, 'category_name' => 'orange' );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );  

printf( '<h2>Generated SQL:</h2><pre>%s</pre>', $query->request );
```

to display the generated `SQL` query. The above example will give you:

```
<h2>Generated SQL:</h2>
<pre>
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID  
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (123) ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
</pre>
```